# Aquatic Snail Identification

Tags: species-identification, zoology, snail, gastropod

I can’t for the life of me find an identification of these snails. They’re thriving in brackish water, but may be freshwater naturally. They’re about .8cm long at their largest. I believe they have live birth due to the lack of eggs but presence of baby snails over the year and a half that I’ve had them.

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Hi, Please try to be more specific like where you found this animal. Check the list of the additional info in the species-identification tag: One or more clear Photos.
A Location where the specimen was found (city/region and/or habitat).
An approximate Size (or photo indicating size).
Additional useful info (e.g., behavior, time of day/year, etc...)
Indication of prior research performed by the asker.
A tag for a specific taxanomic group (e.g., botany, entomology, arachnology, ornithology, ichthyology, etc...).

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a Malayan Live Bearing snail , fairly common in the US aquarium trade. I have inadvertently gotten them into all my tanks. Common aquarium fish can't eat them ( unless you crush them on the glass). I did not know they can tolerate brackish water. Yhey will get to 1.5 mm.